# Can an expanded dominant precede a cadential 6/4 chord?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, voice-leading

My textbook actually says that you should avoid this because it contradicts what the cadential 4 is supposed to do but using the given melody (which I couldnt change) this is the best harmonization I could come up with. Can someone please tell me if they think that it is right or should the expansion of a dominant chord not precede a cadential 6/4? To my ears it sounds good enough but if someone has a better suggestion (especially for bar 3) then I am very interested to hear.

[image]

Comment: In your example, is the soprano, bass, both, or neither fixed? If the soprano isn't fixed, I'd suggest changing it. If the soprano *is* fixed, consider using an accented non-chord tone at the start of Bar 4.

Comment: Only the soprano is fixed. Unfortunately I cant use non-chord tones yet. And anyway, if I could change the soprano, why would you change it and to what?

Comment: A melody of D-A-A-C-B-A-G looks problematic to harmonize if both the soprano and your bass were fixed. If only the bass was fixed, I'd change the soprano so it supports I6/4-V-I better across Bars 3-4. Since you say only the soprano is fixed, I'm more prone to changing Bar 4 to I (or I6)-V(7)-I and possibly change the A-C soprano to an inversion of V7.

Answer (score 3):

#### Why "the rule" is "the rule"

The danger of preceding a cadential 6-4 with an expanded V chord — especially a V7 chord — is that the C6-4 tends to undermine the tension of the dominant chord and winds up sounding like a I chord.

That is, there is a risk that the C6-4 winds up sounding like the resolution of the dominant, rather than a continuation of it.

The question here, however, is both one of following "the rules", but also one of aesthetics. To my ear it also sounds fine as is, so ignoring the rule is okay (especially since this is just for your own purposes, not for a grade).

#### To follow, or not to follow, and how

But if one is to follow the rules strictly, then the core problem is that the melody is not well constructed. The melody more-or-less forces the use of an expanded V chord, which turns the C6-4 into more of a passing chord rather than a cadential chord.

If the priority is following the guidelines laid out in the book, then in measure 3, change the A on beat 2 to B. That will allow for the reharmonization of that measure with the least disruption to the melody as composed.

#### Reharmonization

If you really, really, *really* want to keep the melody as is and avoid the C6-4 preceding by an expanded dominant, then here's a reharmonization that works, by way of some chromaticism. Measure 3, beat by beat, becomes `iii common-tone-dim-7 ii7 -`

#### Other issues

- m. 1: beat 1–2, hidden fifths between soprano and tenor
- m. 2–2: beat 4–1, hidden octaves between tenor and bass

[image: OP exercise reharmonized]

Comment: if I change the A to B as you suggest, would the 1st half of the 3rd bar be harmonized with tonic harmony and the second with subdominant harmony? Also, is it ok moving back to I after being on ii?

Comment: @armani iii would be better than I, then back to ii.

Comment: I havent learned that chord yet so cant use it :( I have only learned I V and inversions of V as well as the subdominant chords.

Comment: @armani As a suggestion, just take this exercise as an example of how things can go wrong, and see if you can compose a different melody that better fits the rules of harmony you've learned so far.

Comment: Wait, what If I leave bar 3 as is but instead of having the cadential 64 chord I do a I V I for the ^3 ^2 ^1 in the last bar?

Comment: @armani This is turning into an extended discussion more appropriate to chat. If Richard and/or I have answered your question, please upvote, and we can discuss as much as desired in the chat room.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* have a cadential six-four chord after a prolongation of the dominant, but in doing so I would argue that you actually lose the function of that chord as a cadential six-four. Instead, since you've already got scale-degree 5 in the bass, this cadential six-four actually becomes just a pedal six-four that continues to prolong dominant. (Obviously the cadential six-four is a specific subtype of the pedal six-four, but to me a key difference is what comes before it; a six-four is only cadential, in my ears, if it's not directly preceded by a dominant prolongation.)

Putting a proper cadential six-four in m. 4 creates one of those frustrating issues in voice leading where one change requires multiple earlier changes to make it work. In order for this to work, I'd argue you would need to:

- Change m. 3 into a prolongation of ii, likely with the opening scale-degree 5 harmonized by I.
- Doing that would necessitate a change in m. 2, because we don't want ii moving directly to I. Thus m. 2 should end with a IV chord.
- Which then requires a change at the start of m. 2, because ii–I–IV is a little nonsensical in this style. Better would be to have a harmonization of V–I–IV in m. 2.

Comment: Why is it ok going from IV back to I but not from ii back to I?

Comment: In the eighteenth-century style, it's relatively rare for ii to move to I. IV does, but ii typically moves to V.

Comment: so is ii like a "go only to dominant chord" then? So if you are in 18th century, once you go ii theres no going back?

Comment: @armani In most cases, yes. Similarly, although IV can move to ii, ii typically doesn't move to IV. So, as you say, once you hit ii, your options are either to expand it or go to V.

Comment: I understand that within subdominant harmony there is a harmonic syntax but I was not aware that you couldnt go back to I after reaching ii.... I know lots of chord progressions with I ii I ii etc. This progression is very common, I cant believe it is not a thing in classical music

Comment: @armani - Wait, which pieces use I-ii-I-ii? I can't even recall any video game music, jazz, or rock that uses that chord progression.

Comment: Dekkadeci.. I know a lot of music that uses that chord progression.... Listen to a song called upside down by jack johnson... this is such a common chord progression.. it is funny how you can say that. It goes to show that music theory has got a long way to go before we can stop being creative.